# Excel Help: How to scan a row and return the value of the first cell in that column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a matrix of numbers and the matrix has column header -- say like this:

```
a b c d e f 
0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0
```

What I want to do is to search for each row for the element 1 and return its column header. For example if I scan the first row, I should return 'd'. Similarly if I scan the second row, I should return 'c'. Which combination of formula works good here?

Comment: =hlookup(bla,blah,blahh,false) is the function you are looking for.  I don't have time ATM to do a full answer, but I'll try and be more complete with an offical answer later unless someone else helps before then.

Comment: hlookup doesn't seem to work. guess it has got to do with the row index num option. appreciate if you could provide me an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a   b   c   d   e   f       
0   0   0   1   0   0   d   =INDEX($A$3:$F$3,1,MATCH(1,A4:F4,0))
0   0   1   0   0   0   c   =INDEX($A$3:$F$3,1,MATCH(1,A5:F5,0))
```

Trust this helps

Comment: @kpnane ;P good luck